# Why is Eclipse not recognizing Java libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

Possibly I am misunderstanding the problem, so I may be asking the wrong question.  I am using Mac OSX 10.8.3 and I am creating an applet in eclipse.  When I try using `import java.*` where `*` is `awt`, `applet`, `util`, etc.

Eclipse shows errors, basically behaving as if it does not recognize the Java libraries.  In the preferences I have the Java SE 6 JRE selected.  I tried lowering the compiler compliance level to 1.6 but it didn't seem to do anything.

For some of the classes I imported the code was written on a windows machine, but I don't see how that would matter.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Just making sure, but you do have Java installed don't you?

Comment: @Chris Cooney: eclipse can't run without java, so it must be installed.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the imports, and then Eclipse should detect that the imports you need are not imported.  Then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to organize your imports, and Eclipse should automatically retrieve every import you need.

Also, you should never import more than you have to.  If `import java.*` even worked (which it never will), it would be a horrible practice, because then all those libraries have to be loaded into memory (even the ones you don't need).  To conserve memory space, avoid using `*` with imports (Eclipse does this when you organize the imports).

Answer (score 0):

If you import `java.*` you only import all classes, interfaces, and so on, which are in the `java` folder. To import classes out of utils you will have to import `java.utils.*`. The `*` is does not work recursively. It's better practise to just import classes that you really need. Normally Eclipse suggested automated import statement generations.