# System library not working in eclipse after update

Tags: java, eclipse, system

I updated my Eclipse and my System stopped working.

Problem is that I'm unable to use for example `System.out.println();` When I write `System.` and press `ctrl + space` - the templates available is empty.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is Eclipse not recognizing Java libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15992779/why-is-eclipse-not-recognizing-java-libraries)

Comment: What versions did you upgrade from and to? What OS are you using? What is the expected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Select the proposal>Template Proposals,SWT Template Proposals,Java Proposals ,Content assist cycling>Template Proposals,SWT Template Proposals,Java Proposals is ticked.

Comment: But the problem isnt the shortcuts, when i write the whole sentence System.out.println(); it still doesnt work